# Routes.push() not working as expected at NextJS

Tags: reactjs, routes, token, next.js

I am trying to redirect the user to the homepage when he tries to access the dashboard of the app without being authenticated, but the Route.push() is not working.

I tried to change Router.push('/') to Router.push('/hey') -> a page that does not exists, and this worked, the route changed. Also when I try to access a path like this Router.push('/auth/signin'), it doesn't work while Router.push('/auth') works

```
import { isAuthenticated } from "../helpers/auth";
import { Component } from "react";
import { Router } from "../routes";

class Ads extends Component {
  // static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
  //   if (ctx && ctx.req) {
  //     console.log(ctx);
  //     //ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: `/` });
  //     ctx.res.end();
  //   } else {
  //     console.log("client side");
  //     console.log(localStorage.getItem("auth-token"));
  //   }
  // }

  handleAuthentication = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("auth-token")) {
      return true;
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.handleAuthentication()) {
      console.log("hey");
    } else {
      Router.pushRoute("/auth/signup");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Dashboard </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Ads;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you were using [next-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-router) dependecy?

Try to use `next/router` (default dependency from nextjs), it works fine in my code:

```
import Router from "next/router";

{ other code... }

Router.push("/auth/signup");
```

Comment: Now i changed to Router.push("/ads", "/"), and the url is changing but is not redirecting. That's my repo: https://github.com/LauraBeatris/befree-front

Comment: Have you tried to add the third parameter shallow true? Seems you want to use an alias, read the documentation here https://github.com/zeit/next.js#shallow-routing `Router.push(href, as, { shallow: true })`

Comment: Now i did this:
 
`
     componentDidMount() {
     const as = "/";

     if (!localStorage.getItem("auth-token")) {
       Router.push("/ads", as, { shallow: true });
       //window.location.reload();
     }
   }
`


And still just changing the url, like, localhost:3000/ads to localhost:3000, thats what i want, but the page still on the same place

Comment: I am experimenting the same problem, Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @LauraBeatris I'm able to use `next/router` and redirect to your `auth/signin` in your repo. I replace `import { Router } from "../routes";` with `import Router from "next/router";`. Then add `Router.push("/auth/signin");` in ln.28 and it works. Redirect unauthorized user to your signin page.

Comment: @user615274 what is your problem? using the same `next-router` dependency?

Comment: Check your console, you may have a runtime error preventing the page from proceeding. In my case I had an error "Maximum update depth exceeded" which was stopping router.push from completing

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem and found a **workaround**, but not a solution. I use `window.location`

```js
//keep your base urls in a global variables file
import { devUri, productionUri } from "../globalVariables";


push = (route = "") => {
  const uri = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? productionUri : devUri;
  window.location = uri + '/' + route
}


push("/auth/signup")
push("/path/to/whatever/route/you/like")
push() //navigates to your base uri
```

}

You could save that function into your version of `globalVariables.js`, and import as needed (much the same way you import other functions from 3rd party modules)

`import { devUri, productionUri, push } from "../globalVariables";`

BTW, I run into the exact same issues you're having: Router.push("/") or any other address that exists just doesn't seem to fire at all, Router.push("/unexistentlocation") works normally

Answer (score 0):

If yo are using useRouter from next/navigation not next/router

Then, the correct implementation would be to do `router.push('/auth/signup')` first, followed by `router.refresh()`

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
const router = useRouter();

router.push('/auth/signup');
router.refresh();
```