# router.push() is not working as expected NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

I am trying to redirect the user to the search results, but router.push() is not working apparently. I changed url to page that don't exist and the route changes, but when it comes to using the url of page already created, nothing happens.

I tried doing something like this, but it's not working either.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const router = useRouter();

const search = () => {
    router.push('/search');
    };
}
```

Comment: could you show the error ?

Comment: How do you call search() function ?

Comment: @Fr0z3n7 `<button onClick={search} className={"btn"}>Search</button>`

Comment: Hi, please check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57474576/7369564 . i hope this helps.

Comment: do you have a directory /pages/search ?

Comment: @Fr0z3n7 yes i have

Comment: @Saurabh Tried everything from there and nothing helps...

Comment: Hi, i tried to run your provided code on my machine and it's working fine on my end. I just wanted to confirm is the search function called when you click on button?

Comment: @Saurabh yes it is. I explained further my problem here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71998242/router-push-working-differently-at-different-times)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution here is to prevent default function by doing something like this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const router = useRouter();

const Search = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        router.push("/search");
    };
```

Comment: doesn't fix it for me, worked the first time, doesn't work on subsequent times...

Comment: Thank you!! I knew it would be my own stupidity. Glad someone else made the same mistake :)

Answer (score 16):

If you are using **Nextjs13**, please be aware to import `useRouter` from `next/navigation`:

```
❌ import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
```

to:

```
✅ import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
```

[Documentation link](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-router)

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation that points this out?

Comment: Good point. Added link.

Comment: This only applies if you're migrating from the `pages` directories to `app` directories - if you're still using `pages`, this doesn't apply.

Comment: doesn't make any difference, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace it with window.location.href = "/"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the correct answer, because nextjs router is buggy

Answer (score 0):

From next js 13 onwards **use router** should be imported from *next/navigation*

```js
✅ import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
```

calling **router.push** for updating the route in shallow(eg: updating query params on the client) might cause the page to reload. Use native APIs (**window.history**) for handling them.

```
  window.history.pushState(null, '', `?${...YOUR_QUERY_PARAMS}`)
```

or

```js
 window.history.replaceState(null, '',NEW_PATH)
```

refer https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating