# Router.push() working differently at different times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, router

I want to use `router.push()` to change the url when clicking `Search` button. However, as far as I have noticed, this function works sometimes and sometimes not. In the final version, after pressing the button, the user should be redirected to the `/search` page with the text entered in the input field. However, this is not happening and I cannot find any error in my code.

That's my search function in `index.js`:

```
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
    const router = useRouter()


    const Search = () => {
        router.push({
            pathname: "/search",
            query: {
                city: searchInput,
            }
            },
        );
    };
```

And that's my form in `index.js`

```
<form className={"flex flex-col items-center mt-44 flex-grow"}>
            <h1 className={"flex justify-center font-bold pt-20 text-4xl"}>Enter address</h1>

            <div className={"flex w-full mt-5 hover:shadow-lg focus-within:shadow-lg max-w-md rounded-full border border-gray-200 px-5 py-3 items-center sm:max-w-xl lg:max-w-2xl"}>

                <input
                    value={searchInput}
                    onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
                    type={"text"} className={"flex-grow focus:outline-none"}/>
                <SearchIcon className={"h-5 text-gray-500"}/>
            </div>


            <div className={"flex flex-col w-1/2 space-y-2 justify-center mt-8 sm:space-y-0 sm:flex-row sm:space-x-4"}>
                <button
                    onClick={Search}
                    className={"btn"}>Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Maybe that's something with my WebStorm configuration as it works sometimes and sometimes not. I don't have any idea to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the default form-submission is interfering with your `Search` function.

You probably want something like:

```js
    const Search = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        router.push({
            pathname: "/search",
            query: {
                city: searchInput,
            }
            },
        );
    };
```

See here for more info: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-preventdefault/