# Confusing behavior from router.push() from useRouter in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, next-router

I'm trying to implement a redirect using push() from useRouter and getting confusing behavior. My use case is simple: after a user signs in, I want to call `router.push('/')` to send them to the home page. However, calling `router.push('/')` after completing the signin flow does nothing. Here's the signin function. It's worth noting that this function gets called from a child component.

```js
const authHandler = useCallback(async (emailCode) => {
    setIsLoading(() => true);
    try {
      const result = await signIn.attemptFirstFactor({
        strategy: 'email_code',
        code: emailCode,
      });
      createAlerts('Success', false);
      router.push('/') // this does nothing;
    } catch (error) {
      handleForeignAlert(error, 'Code is incorrect or expired');
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(() => false);
    }
  });
```

Why doesn't calling `push()` here work? In all the examples in the NextJS docs, it seems like calling it from within a function initiated by a click is exactly what I should do.

The only times `router.push('/')` does work is from within a useEffect() call after I manually reload the page, like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (userId) {
      router.push('/');
    }
  }, [userId]);
```

Also worth noting is that other router methods, like `reload()`, work fine in the same place.

What rule or behavior am I missing here?

Comment: What does `createAlerts` do ?

Comment: @ShivamJha it just sets an alert state, which gets passed into an Alert component.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454034/routes-push-not-working-as-expected-at-nextjs

Comment: If `createAlerts` ultimately calls [`window.alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) then all code execution will stop until the user dismisses the alert dialog.

Comment: Does it work when you remoev `createAlerts('Success', false);`?